# Where can I read about thermodynamics of computation?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, entropy, computational-physics

I'm a physics undergraduate student taking a statistical and thermal physics course. Somehow, I came across Maxwell's demon and the violation of second law. However, the article involved logical reversibility and thermodynamics of computation. Please suggest materials which are self contained as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is often covered in statistical mechanics books but not really in a sufficient way.

However, in their book [The End of Certainty](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-VI8093PJuUC&redir_esc=y), Prigogine and Stengers discuss Maxwell's demon and the effect of time reversion in simulation starting from configurations far out of equilibrium. The core of the book is not on this topic but I remembered it is discussed through one of the chapters. This book requires no prior mathematical skills.

You may also found more detailed discussions in [this collection of resources](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750307595) but it is clearly more technical as it is a collection of scientific papers centered on Maxwell's demon.